# Display sqlite data on listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have to show saved sqlite data on a listview. But only one column's data is enough to show.Here is my codes. I want to get "tarih" column's data.

```
public class TarihDataSource {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseOlusturma dbOlustur;
private String []allColumns = {"tarih","gunluknotu","resim"};

public TarihDataSource(Context context) {
    dbOlustur = new DatabaseOlusturma(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbOlustur.getReadableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbOlustur.close();
}

public List<TarihListHelper> getAllTarih() {
    List<TarihListHelper> tarihlistesi = new ArrayList<TarihListHelper>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query("gunluker", allColumns, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        TarihListHelper comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
        tarihlistesi.add(comment);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return tarihlistesi;
}

private TarihListHelper cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
    TarihListHelper comment = new TarihListHelper();
    comment.setTarih(cursor.getString(1));
    return comment;
  }

}
```

What is the wrong in this codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should help you.

```
public List<TarihListHelper> getAllTarih()
{       
    List<TarihListHelper> tarihlistesi = new ArrayList<TarihListHelper>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DB_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        TarihListHelper tarihlistesi= cursorToComment(cursor);
        tarihlistesi.add(comment);


    }

    cursor.close();
    return tarihlistesi;
}
```

Where `columns` is the `String[]` which contains the `names of all the columns in your database table.`

This way you will get all the columns, then you can select from which column do want to read data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: TarihListHelper data = cursor.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DB_COMMENT_COL));
        comments.add(data); // the List you will pass to ListView for displaying data   I did'nt understand this row.cursor.getString returns String type.But data's type is TarihListeHelper

Comment: TarihListHelper data = cursor.getType(cursor.getColumnIndex("tarih"));  This is giving error.

Comment: Would you care to post the logcat?

Comment: No no.it is not accepted. cursor.getType(...) returns int. But We have TarihListHelper type.

Comment: type cast the data returned by getType to TarihListHelper

Comment: what can i write instead of DB_COMMENT_COL constant?

Comment: Seriously dude. Replace it with the name of the column you want to get data from. You also look at android documentatoin as well.

Comment: Cannot cast from int to TarihListHelper it is saying. when i write my column's name.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need an *Adapter* to your list. In your case i think that a **SimpleCursorAdapter** is the best.

Check [this official page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) and [this example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TarihDataSource {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseOlusturma dbOlustur;
private final Context context;
private String []allColumns = {"tarih","gunluknotu","resim"};

public TarihDataSource(Context _context) {
    context = _context;
    dbOlustur = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbOlustur.getReadableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbOlustur.close();
}

public List<TarihListHelper> getAllTarih() {
    List<TarihListHelper> tarihlistesi = new ArrayList<TarihListHelper>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query("gunluker", allColumns, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        TarihListHelper comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
        tarihlistesi.add(comment);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return tarihlistesi;
}

private TarihListHelper cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
    TarihListHelper comment = new TarihListHelper();
    comment.setTarih(cursor.getString(1));
    return comment;
  }

}
```

Try this.